# How to get a flat List of elements that belongs to elements in a List using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to get a List of Components that belongs to a given List of Projects.

Since I'm starting working with stream, I cannot figure out how to do this.

```
 projects.stream()
         .map(p -> p.getComponents())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since `Project.getComponents()` returns a `Collection<ProjectComponent>` the previous code will return a `List<Collection<ProjectComponent>>` however I wanted to return a `List<ProjectComponent>` how can I do this?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [**`flatMap`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

```
projects.stream()
        .flatMap(p -> p.getComponents().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[**`flatMap`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) will essentially flatten the nested streams i.e from `Stream<Stream<R>>` to `Stream<R>` in which case you then collect the streams elements into a `List<ProjectComponent>`.

Comment: It works like a charm.

Really nice, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Done! I was trying to figure out how to do that hehe